# querying github API for users with README that matches text

Tags: github-api

I would like to retrieve users with repositories that contain a README file that contains text that is matched by a string passed in the query. Is this possible using the GitHub API?

In addition, I would like to include location and language in the query.

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not straightforward using the available API now. However, you can use the API to get what you want.

Be warned that there are over 10 million repositories on Github - it will take a long time. As you can only retrieve a list of 100 repositories per query, you need to use pagination -> more than 100000 requests to get all the repositories. A user is limited to 5000 requests per hour, then you are "banned" for another hour. This will take more than 40 hours, if you're using just one user credentials.

Steps:

1. Get the JSON with all the repositories (https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-all-public-repositories)
2. Use pagination to fetch 100 objects per query (https://developer.github.com/v3/#link-header)
3. Decode the json and retrieve the list of repositories
4. For each repository you need to get the repository url object from the JSON, which gives you the link to the repository.
5. Now you need to get the README contents. There are two ways : 
   a) You use the Github API, by using the repo url and sending a GET request for : https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/readme( https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-the-readme) and then either decode the file (it is encoded using Base64) or you follow the html property of the JSON  e.g "html": "https://github.com/pengwynn/octokit/blob/master/README.md". If there is no README, you will get a 404 Not found code, so you can easily proceed to the next repository.

   b) You just make the URL for the README using step 4 that gives you e.g.             https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World ; and you parse it and transform it into  https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World/README.MD ; however this would be more complicated, in case there is no README.
6. Search through the file for your specific text, and record or not if you have found the text.
7. Iterate until you went through all the repositories.

Advanced things - if you plan on running this more often, I can strongly recommend to use caching https://developer.github.com/v3/#conditional-requests ; You basically store the date + time when you have done the query, and use it later to see if anything has changed in the repository. This will eliminate many of your subsequent queries if you need to have an up-to-date information. You will still have to retrieve the whole list of repositories though. (but then you only do your search for updated repositories)

Of course to make it faster, you can improve this algorithm to make it parallel - you retrieve 100 repositories, then proceed to retrieve the next 100, and in the meanwhile you search if the first 100 repositories contain a README file and if that readme has what you are searching for, and so on. This will make things faster, most certainly. You will need to use some sort of a buffer, as you do not know which terminates faster (getting the repositories list, or searching through them)

Hope it helps.